# How to write a function in Java generalized to take in a map parameter that has different key types?

Tags: java, enums

I have two enums:

```
enum Country { US, etc }
enum Language { EN, etc }
```

I want to be able to write a function that takes in a map that has either enum as the key:

```
checkMap(new HashMap<Language, Long>());
checkMap(new HashMap<Country, Long>());
```

The only ways I have figured out how to do it are the following:

```
1. private void checkMap(Map<? extends Enum, Long> mapParam) {...}

2. private <T> void checkMap(Map<T, Long> mapParam) {...}

3. private void checkMap(Map mapParam) {...}
```

None of these are super specific on the parameters I let in. (1) does the best by making it some subclass of Enum, but complicates much of the logic (which I am greatly simplifying here). (3) I have to do a ton of downstream casting, and I feel it's just generally bad practice.

I feel like I am missing something fairly obvious here.

I also know that I can write two separate method declarations with the different parameters, but there is so much repeat logic and I want to abstract that logic into a function and avoid duplicate code.

Comment: There two classes an entirely unrelated, therefore you're going to struggle with generalising the logic. Can you provide an example of how `checkMap` applies logic generically across these two unrelated classes?

Comment: Just because you have 2 different methods doesn't mean you have to repeat logic. Just use private helper methods for the common stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use your option 2: use a generic type parameter `T`. In your example the methods are `private` so you have complete control over which methods can delegate to `checkMap`, and so do not need to be so concerned about delegations using inappropriate key types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface - make Country and Language implement some made-up interface and use it in method declaration:

```
interface Dummy{}
enum Country implements Dummy {...}
enum Language implements Dummy {...}

private checkMap(Map<Dummy, Long> map) {...}
```